# "The instruction at <address> referenced memory at <address>" error

Tags: .net, system-error

We have a system setup where our clients can request reports on their data that we have for them and we're experiencing some problems with these reports.

A report usually deals with massive amounts of data and may run for hours at a time. We have about a dozen .Net 3.5 console applications, one for each report type, that are started with all the right parameters to make a report. The only dependency they have is MySql.Data.dll. They're all running on Windows Server 2003 SP2. Not particular to any specific kind of report, we'll get this popup error:

`The instruction at "<address>" referenced memory at "<address>". The memory could not be "<read/written>". Click on OK to terminate the program`

The processes that are causing these popups are single threaded, not taking up heaping amounts of memory at the time of the popup, the computer's RAM is nowhere near full, the CPU Usage is usually high but not so much that it brings the computer to a halt or anything.

I can't find and any cause for these popups. There are no line numbers, no exceptions in the Application section of the Event Viewer although the popup is logged in the System section of the viewer, and the addresses are all over the place and show no pattern or repetition (even if they did I don't think that'd help). The programs run unattended and if we find there's one of these popups, there's usually hundreds all showing one after another. As soon as you hit ok, there'll be another one. Our reports sometimes finish successfully as well, it's not guaranteed that these errors will appear when our reports are run. Also, clicking OK on the first popup does not seem to terminate the program.

How can I prevent these errors from happening? I can't think of any cause for them. If more information is needed, I'll gladly help however I can.

Comment: Is there any information in the System or Application event logs?

Comment: Application event logs are empty. System event logs don't say anything new. Just info like what computer it happened on and what time it happened.

Comment: You should probably check out the answers in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182622/exceptions-thrown-errors-encountered-after-program-termination/3438858#3438858. Especially the one that includes information about the GetModuleHandle function and the FreeLibrary function (should look into the GetModuleHandleEX function as well)